# It is possible to use Spring Cloud Zuul without SpringBoot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I want to use `Spring Cloud Zuul` without `SpringBoot`. We have an existing project with Spring but I'm having trouble to configure `Zuul` without `SpringBootApplication`.

When I use **@EnableZuulProxy** annotation, I get the following error:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.ZuulProxyConfiguration':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'discovery'; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient'
>   available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>
> No qualifying bean of type
>   'org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient' available

And why it needs a discovery client?

Can I use **spring-cloud-starter-zuul** dependency without spring-boot?

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can use zuul directly via the Netflix OSS bits https://github.com/Netflix/zuul/wiki/Getting-Started